# Setting up 301 Redirection with a URL having double forward slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Help! I am trying to set up my URL http://www.sample.com/blog//press_releases.php to be redirected to /, I already tried to input it in SEO, having /blog//press_releases.php to / and it not working. Also tried to put in to my .htaccess, but nothing seems to work using the following below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)//+(.*)$
RewriteRule // https://www.sample.com/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

I have this existing to my .htaccess file:

```
    Redirect 301 /upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detroit /blog/upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detr‌​oit/
    Redirect 301 /can-you-identify-with-me /blog/can-you-identify-with-me/ 
    Redirect 301 /speech-recognition-success-or-failure-is-not-always-black-o‌​r-white /blog/speech-recognition-success-or-failure-is-not-always-bl‌​ack-or-white/ 
    Redirect 301 /transforming-a-contact-center-father /blog/transforming-a-contact-center-father/ 
    Redirect 301 /the-fifth-game-jinx /blog/the-fifth-game-jinx/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess to remove all multiple slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava, but I tried that and still not redirecting. Should I include my URL to the Rewriterule?

Comment: I have other added redirection going to /blog/, and I have used  Redirect 301 /sample/sample  going to /blog/sample/sample

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean I have other redirection going to /blog/ >>> sample >>> Redirect 301 /upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detroit /blog/upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detroit/

Comment: I have this part in my .htaccess that has "/blog/" redirections, --- Redirect 301 /upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detroit /blog/upcoming-events-iaug-converge-2013-and-telematics-detroit/
Redirect 301 /can-you-identify-with-me /blog/can-you-identify-with-me/
Redirect 301 /speech-recognition-success-or-failure-is-not-always-black-or-white /blog/speech-recognition-success-or-failure-is-not-always-black-or-white/
Redirect 301 /transforming-a-contact-center-father /blog/transforming-a-contact-center-father/
Redirect 301 /the-fifth-game-jinx /blog/the-fifth-game-jinx/

Comment: Does `blog/` directory also have a .htaccess?

Comment: Place my suggested rule **before your existing rules**